# Digital Signature Generation

Tags: x.509, yubikey, self-signed, pfx

In short, I need to place a Digital Signature into slot 9c of my Yubikey. If you generate the certificate from the Yubikey; then the private key is not exportable. So I'm attempting to generate the pfx file from the computer itself so that I can import into multiple keys without the need for multiple different certificates.

I've spent 6+ hours on Google, and it has all become confusing. I assume what I'm wanting is a "self-signed" digital signature certificate.

I ran into the method of using **certreq -new .\certname.txt** by providing simple parameters.

But the only thing I've come to know that I need in my file is:

```
[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=Test Sign, E=email@address.com"
KeyLength = 2048
HashAlgorithm = Sha256
KeyUsage = 0x0080 ; Digital Signature
RequestType = Cert
ValidityPeriodUnits = 1
ValidityPeriod = Years
```

But I'm unsure of what else should be here in order to make it a proper signature certificate.

I want to be able to use this signature file in whatever project I have going.

I messed around with Adobe Acrobat Pro and you can create a digital sig in that program; but it limits the OID to **1.2.840.113583.1.1.10** which is for Adobe.

After; I found a method that says it's possible to generate one via OpenSSL (which I installed); but I'm not quite sure what steps I need to take. All I know is that I need RSA 2048 / SHA256. I'm not even sure by the docs that I read if OpenSSL is a proper route to go. Because I'd need to generate the key, and then export it to pfx / p12 for it to be imported onto the smart card.

Any help to end this nightmare would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be a CA or just generate your self-signed certificate, there is a suggestion for you, which using OpenSSL for done.

You can generate a self-signed end entry certificate by doing these things:

1. Generate your private key for X.509 certificate request (Hereafter abbreviated as "CSR"):

`openssl genrsa -out /path/to/privkey.pem 2048 # Generate RSA private key with 2048 bits`

2. Modify your OpenSSL configurate file for CSR and X.509 certificate extension:

(In my habit, I usually generate a blank CSR and add extensions in signing certificate)

(1). Open the file, create a new section, you can give a name to it (like `[v3_mycert]`).

(2). Add these lines to the new section.
Please remove the "#" if you want to add the extension after it.

```
#authorityInfoAccess=OCSP;URI:http://www.example.com, #caIssuers;URI:http://www.example.com/ca.crt
#crlDistributionPoints=crlDistributionPoint0_sect
extendedKeyUsage=1.2.840.113583.1.1.10
keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, dataEncipherment
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
basicConstraints=critical,CA:FALSE
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid

[crlDistributionPoint0_sect]
fullname=URI:http://www.example.com/foo.crl
```

The format of the section is `KEY=VALUE`. The key can be replaced with the short name and OID of the extension. The value must match with the KEY or it can be identified by OpenSSL. (like `DER:05:00`).
I think you can understand these configurate lines.

3. Generate a blank CSR:

`openssl req -new -key /path/to/privkey.pem -out /path/to/cert.csr -addext v3_mycert`

And type the subject information of the certificate.
NOTICE: You have to input all subjects if you do not change the settings in OpenSSL configurate file.

4. Self-sign the CSR and you will get the certificate:

`openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in /path/to/cert.csr -signkey /path/to/privkey.pem -out /path/to/cert.crt`

And in OpenSSL (1.1.1 or newly), the default algorithm is SHA256. "RSA" is your key algorithm, "2048" is your key bit.

Comment: Thanks for this! So I found "openssl.cnf" (windows machine); and there seems to be a lot of stuff already in there. Am I editing the existing openssl.cnf file and removing all other existing configs or does it support a new config I can specify to load.

I assume I edit the existing one, but add [v3_mycert] and then anything under that belongs specifically to the certificate I wish to create?

And then I would call [v3_mycert] when I generate the blank CSR?

Comment: Oort: The subcommand of OpenSSL (like `genrsa`|`req`|`x509`) all support a option `-config`, you can create a new OpenSSL file and use it. and sections spilt with "section header" (`[v3_mycert]` is a header).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I've set everything up but it's throwing "Duplicate extension: v3_mycert". I assume that meant that v3_mycert is being called elsewhere so I checked my files and I am not finding it. Attempting to locate the root cause on Google.

That error is thrown when attempting to execute the "openssl req" command with v3_mycert at the end.

Comment: Alright; after reading the documentation; I have made a certificate, and it has the proper values. The only part of the certificate I'm concerned about is "Enhanced Key Usage": Unknown Key Usage (1.2.840.113583.1.1.10) -- I believe that is the OID that Adobe tried to use. And when I was originally researching; I had no idea which one to actually use so I could digitally sign any type of file. Appreciate the help thus far!

Comment: Oort: There are some OIDs I think you may be interested in.
`1.2.840.113583.1.1.5`/`1.2.840.113583.1.1.6`/`1.2.840.113583.1.1.7`/`1.2.840.113583.1.1.9`, you can get the information on [oid-info](http://www.oid-info.com). **If you want to create a certificate for PDF signing, you need this OID: `1.2.840.113583.1.1.5`**

Comment: Thanks for those. I've been on a Google frenzy but it appears I'm doing something wrong. I tried with one specific OID, and then with multiple and I get the same result: https://i.imgur.com/PNruq6X.png -- for "Key Usage" I tried your config, and also just with Digital Signature (80) and it seems to do it no matter what I place there.

Comment: Oort: The EKU should be used for advanced usage. If you want to sign a document file, you need this OID: `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.12 `, if you want to sign PDF file, you still need the OID in previous.